# Matrix with missing values in armadillo for cross-validation

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm trying to work with matrices with missing values within Armadillo in c++.
What I mean with missing values is the following: 
suppose I have a 2x2 matrix,

A=[[a b],[c *]]

A has a missing value in A(2,2). That is, it has no value assigned (not even a nan). 
When performing simple operations on A, such as `sum(A,0)` , i.e. summing elements in each column, I would get:
sum_of_A=(a+b,c).

(In other words, the missing value would be ignored although armadillo knows that it's handling a 2x2 object).

All my attempts so far have involved the usage of nans, which are difficult to deal with in my experience.
Can anyone help with me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How *general* does your placeholder value have to be? Depending on what you want to do, you might be able to get away with a suitable choice of identity element, that is, `0` is the identity element for addition, whereas `1` would be used for multiplication. These would be specific instances of what is called a [Monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), which you could define a general class for. I would definitely try to avoid abusing `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @mbw.
Unfortunately, this won't work, since my matrix would be an adjacency one representing a network. In this context, '0' means "no link"  between two nodes and '1' means "link" between 2 nodes. A missing value in my case would mean "not observed".
Thanks a lot, in any case!
Sergio Cobo

Comment: Maybe you should make your problem description a little more concrete then. That is, what types do you want to work with, the actual operation you want to do, and so on. There probably won't be a one size fits all solution. What I knew was merely that you want to do reductions along specific dimensions. Now we're talking about graph algorithms I presume. Without more information about what you actually want to do, it's not easy to be of any help.

Comment: I just wanted to provide a very simple example to start with. I'll try to be concise about my problem now:
The input to my code would be an incomplete adjacency matrix representing observations of a network (i.e. a matrix with missing values). The matrix elements here would be: 0 (no link), 1,2,...n (links of type 1,2...,n). This matrix needs to be incomplete in order to test a predictive model my code aims to build. Implementing this model requires operations such as matrix dimension reduction based on the adjacency matrix described above.
Thanks again for the help, @mbw.
Sergio Cobo